# Require const value for template loop

Tags: c++, templates

How to make a const argument that is known at compile time to work as a template argument in the following code?

Error:

```
test.cpp(13): error: expression must have a constant value
      loop<nd>();
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
template <int Depth>
inline void loop(void){
    std::cout << Depth;
    loop<Depth - 1>();
}
template <>
inline void loop<0>(void){
    std::cout << "end" <<std::endl;
}

inline void broadcast_loop(const int nd){
    loop<nd>();
}

int main(void){
    const int nd = 3;
    broadcast_loop(nd);
}
```

Comment: You're calling `loop` with a value that is not necessarily known at compile time. I think you want `constexpr`, which is not the same as const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments to functions can never be used the way you described, because the definition of the function will never be able to prove that in all calling contexts the argument to the function is a constant expression. Really what you are looking for is `constexpr`, not `const`, but you cannot `constexpr` function arguments (for the reason I just described). What you can do is instead pass the integer in a template:

```
template <int nd>
inline void broadcast_loop(){
    loop<nd>();
}

int main(void){
constexpr int nd = 3;
broadcast_loop<nd>();
```

}

Notice how in my `main` I needed `constexpr`, not just `const`.

Comment: "I needed `constexpr`, not just `const`." Actually, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it this way, because the C++ type system is not strong enough to let you do this. There is no way to enforce that the argument passed to `broadcast_loop` is a *constant expression* (*i.e.,* compile-time constant), so the compiler cannot allow you to use the parameter as a template parameter.

You would have to simply call `loop<nd>()` directly from `main()`, or make `broadcast_loop` take `nd` as a template parameter.